# Lua string.match() problem

Tags: string, lua, match

I want to match a few lines for a string and a few numbers.
The lines can look like

```
"  Code                                             : 75.570 "
```

or

```
"  ..dll                                   :          13.559       1"
```

or

```
"  ..node                                    :  4.435    1.833    5461"
```

or

```
"  ..NavRegions                                     :  0.000         "
```

I want something like

```
local name, numberLeft, numberCenter, numberRight = line:match("regex");
```

But I'm very new to the string matching.

Comment: One question: Do the strings for the name always have either zero or two periods at the front, with the rest of the string being letters?

Comment: There are the two space characters at the beginning of the line, the name follows and there are again space characters, the colon, and 1 or 2 or 3 numbers(unknown amount of space characters again in between and space characters at the end or not. It's really complex, does anybody has a better idea than string matching or maybe a workaround?

Comment: Retagged because Lua doesn't contain the regex libraries.  For more details on Lua pattern matching, see http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Answer (score 5):

This pattern will work for every case:

`%s*([%w%.]+)%s*:%s*([%d%.]+)%s*([%d%.]*)%s*([%d%.]*)`

Short explanation: `[]` makes a set of characters (for example the decimals). The last to numbers use `[set]*` so an empty match is valid too. This way the number that haven't been found will effectively be assigned `nil`.

Note the difference between using `+` `-` `*` in patterns. More about patterns [in the Lua reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1).

This will match any combination of dots and decimals, so it might be useful to try and convert it to a number with `tonumber()` afterwards.

Some test code:

```
s={
"  Code                                             : 75.570 ",
"  ..dll                                   :          13.559       1",
"  ..node                                    :  4.435    1.833    5461",
"  ..NavRegions                                     :  0.000         "
}
for k,v in pairs(s) do
    print(v:match('%s*([%w%.]+)%s*:%s*([%d%.]+)%s*([%d%.]*)%s*([%d%.]*)'))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point:

```
s="  ..dll                                   :          13.559       1"
for w in s:gmatch("%S+") do
        print(w)
end
```

You may save these words in a table instead of printing, of course. And skip the second word.

Answer (score 1):

@Ihf Thank you, I now have a working solution.

```
local moduleInfo, name = {};
for word in line:gmatch("%S+") do
    if (word~=":") then
        word = word:gsub(":", "");
        local number = tonumber(word);
        if (number) then
            moduleInfo[#moduleInfo+1] = number;
        else
            if (name) then
                name = name.." "..word:gsub("%$", "");
            else
                name = word:gsub("%$", "");
            end
        end
    end
end
```

@jpjacobs Really nice, thanks too. I'll rewrite my code for synthetic reasons ;-) I'll implement your regex of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have no understanding of the Lua language, so I won't help you there.
But in Java this regex should match your input

`"([a-z]*)\\s+:\\s+([\\.\\d]*)?\\s+([\\.\\d]*)?\\s+([\\.\\d]*)?"`

You have to test each group to know if there is data left, center, right

Having a look at [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4), it could look like this. No guarantee, I did not see how to escape `.` (dot) which has a special meaning and also not if `?` is usable in Lua.

`"([a-z]*)%s+:%s+([%.%d]*)?%s+([%.%d]*)?%s+([%.%d]*)?"`

Comment: This looks very close. You're requiring at least two numbers though, if I parse that correctly. Shouldn't another of the digit groupings have a `?`...and also, wouldn't it be better to use `(\\d*\\.?\\d*)` for those groupings, to make the matches more precise?

Comment: @Blak corrected for the missing `?` indeed `(\\d*\\.?\\d*)` is more precise.